# Get value of td table using hierarchy css (without id/classes) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying get the value of `td` value usgin hierarchy css with javascript.
This is my code:

This code returns the value of first `td` when I click in element, but my alert is undefined.

How I can solve it?

```js
var ee = $(".table tr td:nth-child(1)").attr('value');

$(".table").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    alert(ee);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [Both work](https://jsfiddle.net/bhwqh2j4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<td>` do not have *values*, that's why:

```
var ee = $(".table tr td:nth-child(1)").text();

$(".table").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    alert(ee);
});
```

Your click event is fine. You're just grabbing an undefined item, hence why the alert is acting how it is. You need to grab `<td>--this--</td>`

**Helpful Advice:**

This isn't going to give you the text of the 1st `<td>`, since that's not how nth child works with this. If you want that, try this as a selector:

```
var ee = $(".table tr td:eq(0)").text();
```

*0* would be the *first*, *1* is *second*, *2* is *third*, etc.

You can also *drop* the e.preventDefault() and e in the function heading. A table has no default action unlike a form or button.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know the function `text()`, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var ee = $(".table tr td:nth-child(1)").html();
```

instead of

```
var ee = $(".table tr td:nth-child(1)").attr('value');
```

First one would refer to a `value` property on the tag, like an input one. eg : `<input type="radio" name="field" value="1" >`